# Offset + ajax пагинация в Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination

Есть код для вывода постов начиная с 3-го:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array ('posts_per_page' => 9, 'offset' => 10, 'orderby' => 'date' ));
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts() ) {$query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template', 'loop' );
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Нет записей.</p>';
}
```

Но он не работает из-за offset.

Код пагинации:

```
<div id="preload"></div>
<?php if ( $query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <script>
        var posts = '<?php echo serialize($query->query_vars); ?>';
        var page = '<?php echo (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1; ?>';
        var pages = '<?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?>';
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

JS:

```
if ($('#preload').length) {
    var page = 1;
    $(window).scroll($.throttle(200, function() {
        var bottomOffset = 1500; // отступ
        var data = {
          'action': 'loadmore',
          'query': posts,
          'page': page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - bottomOffset) && !$('body').hasClass('loading')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajax.url,
                data: data,
                type:'POST',
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                $('body').addClass('loading');
                    if (page < pages) {
                        $('.loader').show();
                    }
                },
                success:function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $('#preload').before(data);
                        $('.loader').hide();
                        $('body').removeClass('loading');
                        page++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }));
}
```

functions.php

```
function load_posts() {
  global $post;
  $args = unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['query']));
  $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // следующая страница
  $args['posts_per_page'] = 9;

  $posts = get_posts($args);
  if (count($posts) > 0) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
      if (!in_array($post->ID)) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        get_template_part('template', 'loop');
      }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }

  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'load_posts');
```

Без offset пагинация отлично работает, но с offset подгружает одну и ту же страницу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2647/kak-ispolzovat-parametr-offset-ne-lomaya-paginatsiyu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В functions.php сделал так:

```
function load_posts() {
  global $post;
  $args = unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['query']));

  $current_page = max( 1, $_POST['page'] );

  $per_page = 9;
  $offset_start = 19;

  $offset = ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page + $offset_start;

  $args['offset'] = $offset;
  $args['paged'] = $current_page;
  $args['posts_per_page'] = $per_page;

  $posts = get_posts($args);
  if (count($posts) > 0) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
      if (!in_array($post->ID)) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        get_template_part('template', 'loop');
      }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'load_posts');
```